# Does changing reference of nested object is changing reference to root object?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm not fully sure how I can test that - Please advise

Lets say that we have object X

```
{
    a: {
        b: {
            c: true
        }
    }
}
```

Then we are mutating it so we are having object Y

```
{
    a: {
        b: {
            ...X.a.b.c, 
            c: false
        }
    }
}
```

Question if we compare X === Y (using strict equal) it will return true because the reference of compared objects is the same but not for child objects?

Comment: Using `==` or `===` makes no difference in this case. You need to post actual code. If you have `X = {a:{b:{c:true}}}` and `Y = {a:{b:{...X.a.b.c, c:false}}}` then `X===Y` and `X==Y` will be false, as you are comparing two distinct objects, not two references to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two nested objects, we should do deep comparison. === will only check for equality of reference of the objects. For deep comparison we can use loadash's isEqual function.`_.isEqual(X, Y);` it will return true if they are equal.

Or you can just stringify both objects and compare them  `JSON.stringify(X) === JSON.stringify(Y)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the part of code where you are using spread operator (...X.a.b.c).

X.a.b.c is holding a primitive value. So, if we try to use spread operator on a primitive, it won't result anything.

For Example,

```
let a = {
  x: 2
};

let b = {
  ...a.x
};

let c = {
  x: 2
}

let e = a;

console.log(b); // Logs {} to the console
console.log(a===c); // Logs false to the console
console.log(a==c); // Logs false to the console
console.log(a==e); // Logs true to the console
```

> In comparison part, if we compare two variables which hold reference to
>   two different objects then it will return `false` but if we compare
>   two variables which hold reference to the same object then it will
>   return `true`.

Refer the below MDN docs for `Object.is` function for more information on different ways to compare objects and primitives.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is